# SQL Select text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, text, sql-like

I'm trying to make a sql select statement, but I'm confused about something and I'm not sure how to look for it.

Example:

Given the parameter "AB12", on my SQL I will have a field with value "AB"

I'm trying to do is something like:

```
Select * From SampleTable Where SampleField+'%' LIKE SampleParameter
```

I'm tried to explain my best.

Thanks all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `LIKE` pattern always goes on the right, not the left.  Presumably, you intend:

```
Where SampleParameter LIKE SampleField + '%'
```

Comment: Put some sample data and expected results in your question then please, @MarcRamiroAlpuente

Comment: @MarcRamiroAlpuente it works in the case you described - finding a field that contains only `AB` when the parameter is `AB12`. You'll have to post what you *actually* tried.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Where SampleField LIKE SampleParameter + '%'
```